# how to get facebook albumName

Tags: c#, facebook

i have problem with get facebook album name.i use this code:

```
private void LoadAlbumName()
    {

        dynamic albums = new FacebookMediaObject();
        albums = _fb.Get("me/albums/");
        foreach (dynamic albumInfo in albums.data)
        {
            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(
                () =>
                {
                    dynamic albumsPhotos = _fb.Get(albumInfo.id + "/photos");
                }));
        }
    }
```

when i run i get null

Answer (score 0):

Have you asked for user_photos permission? Additionally I think the correct api call is "/me/albums".